# Entity Framework: multiple database versions

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

We have a product that operates off a third party database which has a schema we cannot modify. At each install site, that database could be a wide range of versions. Some columns might exist in one database, but not in others, or might have different data types.

What are EF best practices for dealing with this problem? Obviously it will require some situational coding with different versions in mind, but my specific question is how to handle this with as little situational programming in the logic as possible. For the majority of database calls, the changes will not affect us, and I would like to retain the ability to write one query as often as possible.

We are able to know the version of the database at runtime, so we do not have to do any sleuthing to figure that out. We are running Entity Framework 6, but we are not too far into the project, so if later versions of EF can solve this better, we can switch.

Correct me if this is a duplicate, but I could only find existing questions related to accessing multiple databases at once. In this question, I would like to have only one database being passed around without having to specify "DbContextV10" and "DbContextV11". Generating a common interface will work to some degree, but it really depends on the magnitude of the version changes, which we do not know going forward, and we want to minimize our work in the future.

Comment: This does not sound like a situation that any ORM will handle very well.

Comment: Keep everything as generic as possible and only create one-offs any time the version affects your code. Just because there are 14 versions of something does not necessarily mean that those versions have to be breaking changes to your code. It really depends on how you interface with the database. If you want more than just a general comment (like this one) you will have to provide an [mcve]. Perhaps 2 or 3 versions of a schema where the (EF) code needs to stay generic...